# In Google Spreadsheets, how do I make a cell display a value randomly depending on a percentage in another cell

Tags: google-sheets

I want to make a cell display the word, 'YES' and 'NO' where the chance of the cell landing on'YES' would depend on the % in another cell.

(E.g. 100% would mean there is a 100% chance on the cell landing on 'YES', 99% would mean a 99% chance on cell landing on 'YES', etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple. Let's say the chance is 0.6 (60%), then `=rand()<0.6` would have ~60% chance of being TRUE. I tested 100 functions on both Excel and Google Spreadsheet and confirmed the result.

There are two ways of showing "YES"/"NO". One is using `if()`. Another is `=(rand()<0.6)*1` which forces the result into number 0 or 1, then using custom number format of `"YES";;"NO";@`